# What is the best way to Stream Audio on a website

Tags: streaming, stream

I am updating a website for a radio station and they would like to be able stream previously broadcast sports games on the site. Most games are 2 - 3 hours long so the files are really large. What would be the best way to offer these games so users can listen to them without having to download the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe using flash would be best then you wouldnt have to rely on any special client software and you could build a flash applet for it,

I believe that their flash player reads and buffers a file off of their server

the website here streams podcasts using flash
[Deadworkers.com](http://deadworkers.com/network/?cat=7)